SOAP response returns string
I have run a PHP curl soap request but am having issues with parsing the string response.
It is returned as a string but I can't seem to be able to convert it to xml. I have tried using xml parsers xml DOM and simple xml but can't get out the data from as xml.
Below is the result from xmlDOM it returns it as just text content
DOMDocument Object ( [doctype] => [implementation] => (object value omitted) [documentElement] => (object value omitted) [actualEncoding] => [encoding] => [xmlEncoding] => [standalone] => 1 [xmlStandalone] => 1 [version] => 1.0 [xmlVersion] => 1.0 [strictErrorChecking] => 1 [documentURI] => /xxx/xxx/xxxxxxxx/ [config] => [formatOutput] => [validateOnParse] => [resolveExternals] => [preserveWhiteSpace] => 1 [recover] => [substituteEntities] => [nodeName] => #document [nodeValue] => [nodeType] => 9 [parentNode] => [childNodes] => (object value omitted) [firstChild] => (object value omitted) [lastChild] => (object value omitted) [previousSibling] => [nextSibling] => [attributes] => [ownerDocument] => [namespaceURI] => [prefix] => [localName] => [baseURI] => /var/www/quoting/ [textContent] => 0 Response successful Success OF00021 Offnet Single Play ADSL 2+ Availability code AVC001 Availability message Product available Minimum downstream speed 1.5Mbit/s Maximum downstream speed 4Mbit/s Worst minimum guaranteed downstream speed 1Mbit/s Average downstream speed 2.5Mbit/s Minimum upstream speed 0.448Mbit/s Maximum upstream speed 1.28Mbit/s Required appointment type No Appointment Earliest delivery date 2024-04-17 Conditional availability Product available Allowed order type Provide Feature value code FT00210 PC00042 Single Play FTTP Availability code AVC009_002 Availability message Product availability could not be determined due to mandatory value ONT reference or Access line id or Telephone number or Address details missing PC00071 Single Play SOGEA Availability code AVC009_001 Availability message Product availability could not be determined due to mandatory value Access line id or Telephone number or Address details missing )


Here is the string I am returned when I echo the response:
0Response successfulSuccessOF00021Offnet Single Play ADSL 2+Availability codeAVC001Availability messageProduct availableMinimum downstream speed1.5Mbit/sMaximum downstream speed4Mbit/sWorst minimum guaranteed downstream speed1Mbit/sAverage downstream speed2.5Mbit/sMinimum upstream speed0.448Mbit/sMaximum upstream speed1.28Mbit/sRequired appointment typeNo AppointmentEarliest delivery date2024-04-16Conditional availabilityProduct availableAllowed order typeProvideFeature value codeFT00210PC00042Single Play FTTPAvailability codeAVC009_002Availability messageProduct availability could not be determined due to mandatory value ONT reference or Access line id or Telephone number or Address details missingPC00071Single Play SOGEAAvailability codeAVC009_001Availability messageProduct availability could not be determined due to mandatory value Access line id or Telephone number or Address details missing


Any help appreciated as unsure of how I can parse this correctly
